# Android Google Analytics in my android application

Tags: android, analytics

Am looking for a way to implement Google analytics in my android app.
I have searched for example codes and i completely cant understand how it works.

Could someone please give me a sample code on how to use Google Analytics?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: It would be useful to post an example you've found and explain what exactly about it you don't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the online samples to integrate Google analytics to app but i found this one best of all [Android Hive](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/08/android-integrating-google-analytics-v4/).

Comment: If this helps you please accept it as answer.

Comment: Thanks very much Chintan...this is the solution